# Removing blankspace before string

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I would like to count the occurence of strings from certain file using pipelines, without awk and sed command.

my_file content:

```
ls -al
bash
cat datoteka.txt
cat d.txt | sort | less
/bin/bash
```

terminal command that I use:

```
 cat $my_file | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr '|' '\n' | xargs -r -L1 basename | sort | uniq -c | xargs -r -L1 sh -c 'echo $1 $0'
```

desired output:

```
bash 2
cat 2
less 1
ls 1
sort 1

In my case, I get:
bash 2
cat 2
ls 1
_sort 1 (not counted )
_less 1 (not counted )
```

Sort and less comand are not counted because of the whitespace (I marked with _ ) infront of those two strings. How shall I improve my code, to remove this blank space before "sort" and "less"? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Here is a second and longer example of an input file:

```
nl /etc/passwd
seq 1 10 | tr "\n" ","
seq 1 10 | tr -d 13579 | tr -s "\n "
seq 1 100 | split -d -a 2 -l10 - blabla-
uname -a | cut -d" " -f1,3
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd > fst
cut -d: -f3 /etc/passwd > scnd 
ps -e | column
echo -n ABC | wc -m -c
cmp -s dat1.txt dat1.txt ; echo $?
diff dat1 dat2
ps -e | grep firefox
echo dat1 dat2 dat3 | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I {} -p ln -s {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code in the question, as you were aware, was with the `cut` statement.   This replaces `cut` with a shell `while` loop that also includes the `basename` command:

```
$ tr '|' '\n' <my_file | while read cmd other; do basename "$cmd"; done | sort | uniq -c | xargs -r -L1 sh -c 'echo $1 $0'
bash 2
cat 2
less 1
ls 1
sort 1
```

#### Alternate Sorting

The above sorts the results alphabetically by the name of the command.  If instead we want to sort in descending numerical order of number of occurrences, then:

```
tr '|' '\n' <file2 | while read cmd other; do basename "$cmd"; done | sort | uniq -c | xargs -r -L1 sh -c 'echo $1 $0' | sort -snrk2
```

Applying this command to the second input example in the question:

```
$ tr '|' '\n' <file2 | while read cmd other; do basename "$cmd"; done | sort | uniq -c | xargs -r -L1 sh -c 'echo $1 $0' | sort -snrk2
tr 4
cut 3
seq 3
echo 2
ps 2
cmp 1
column 1
diff 1
grep 1
nl 1
split 1
uname 1
wc 1
xargs 1
```

Comment: I have another question for you, because I'm using your command. This command is sorting columns with strings, I would like to sort also column with numbers:

`*Current output:*
cmp 1
cut 2 
diff 1
echo 2
seq 3 

*desired output:*
seq 3
cut 2
echo 2
cmp 1
diff 1`

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: @ZeroZek That is easy enough.  See updated answer for sorting in reverse numerical order by number of occurrences.

Comment: Now I get ordered correctly by numbers but strings that have the same number are not ordered correctly: seq 3 ps 2 echo 2 . Thanks for help and sorry for bothering you so much :)

Comment: @ZeroZek Hmm.  It works for me.  At the bottom of your question, please add in, as an update, the input file that you are using now so I can see what is going on.  (Don't change what is in the question now, just add on at the bottom.)

Comment: @ZeroZek Very good.  I revised the sorting method in the new answer.  Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS='|' read -ra commands; do 
    for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do 
        set -- $cmd     # unquoted to discard irrelevant whitespace
        basename $1
    done
done < myfile | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
while read num cmd; do 
   echo "$cmd $num"
done
```

```
bash 2
cat 2
less 1
ls 1
sort 1
```